# iPhone app opens on iPad like an iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, info.plist

The most recent version of my app was rejected from the app store review process. I believe it's because it opens up on iPad and the user interface isn't set up for this.

But I can't figure out how this is happening. Previous versions of the App opened in the iPhone sized screen  with a 2x button. This version opens up full screen. Is it because my new xib has auto layout turned on?

More info:

Device family setting is set to: iPhone.

I don't have anything in info.plist that says NSMainNibFile~ipad.

Comment: is there any specific reason they have mentioned for rejecting the app?

Comment: They sent a screenshot of the app laying out strangely. I can only duplicate this behavior in the iPad simulator but the screenshot they sent was sized to iPhone dimensions. It looked like a cropped version of the iPad running the app.

Comment: First of all it has nothing to do with the AutoLayout. Have you configured it for iPhone 5 or not?

Comment: Yup it's running great full screen on iPhone 5 and also simulator version iPhone 4. I can't replicate Apple's strange layout except when running simulator as iPad.

Comment: the only reason i can think is that somewhere it is also set to be an iPad app but as the interface is not ready so thats why Apple's app approval team has rejected it

Comment: Yeah that's my thoughts as well. After screwing around for an hour trying to stop the thing from opening full on the iPad I've decided to just get the app to run on the iPad. Always wanted to do that anyway

Comment: Talked to a friend at NSCoders. He thinks it might be the project file that got screwed up when merging from an old repo. Maybe the interface is saying iPhone but the compile settings are actually iPad/iPhone. Really strange. The app opens in the iPad as an iPhone app at first. it has the weird beveled border around it at a small size and then as soon as my main view controller gets loaded the app goes full screen.

Answer (score 2):

What reason has been given by apple for the rejection of your app?
Since May 1st of this year, apple has made some changes in review process.

[As per the Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/),

> Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store
>   must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must
>   also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5.

So if your iPhone app doesn't support the iPhone 5 resolution then Apple will reject the app.
For more reference [see this also.](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/03/21/after-a-year-of-warnings-apple-will-no-longer-accept-any-apps-that-use-udids-as-of-may-1st/)

Comment: It supports iPhone 5 display. That's also the reason it has constraints based layout. I don't know if constraints are allowing it to open full screen on iPad, but they definitely allow the view to layout full screen whereas before it was hard coded (more or less) to iPhone dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

check the device on setting is selected iphone or not.

[image]

Comment: Device is set to iPhone. When I open in simulator as iPad it still opens full screen iPad dimensions.